# How to create a nested list using the list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have string(str1) that contains the below format. Using the string I have created a list. I am trying to create a nested list using the data.

```
str1 = 'Emp1 Developer Band1 Active\r\nEmp2 Senior-Developer Band2 Inactive\r\nEmp3 Admin Band2 Active'
print(str1.splitlines())
```

Output:

```
['Emp1 Developer Band1 Active', 'Emp2 Senior-Developer Band2 Inactive', 'Emp3 Admin Band2 Active']
```

Can anyone please get me the code to format the above data into a nested list like the below

Expected result:

```
[['Emp1,Developer,Band1,Active'],['Emp2 Senior-Developer Band2 Inactive'],[Emp3 Admin Band2 Active]]
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what the expected result is. As it stands, space is replaced by comma in the first line of the text but not the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that 3 list `[Emp3 Admin Band2 Active]`may typo,

please try nested list comprehensions:

```
str1 = 'Emp1 Developer Band1 Active\r\nEmp2 Senior-Developer Band2 Inactive\r\nEmp3 Admin Band2 Active'
#print(str1.splitlines())

print([[y for y in x.split()] for x in str1.splitlines()])
```

output:

```
[['Emp1', 'Developer', 'Band1', 'Active'], ['Emp2', 'Senior-Developer', 'Band2', 'Inactive'], ['Emp3', 'Admin', 'Band2', 'Active']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
z = [[','.join(y for y in x.split())] for x in str1.splitlines()]
print(z)
```

Explanataion:

1. split str1 according to the \n
2. for each of the lines, split it according to to the whitespaces
3. join the result of 2(iterable) with the ',' character

read about:

- [nested list comprehension](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/)
- [split function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)
- [join function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

Comment: @Chandra i'll be happy if you mark the answer as correct :) , and vote.

Answer (score -1):

Easy:

```
>>> [[x] for x in str1.splitlines()]
[['Emp1 Developer Band1 Active'], ['Emp2 Senior-Developer Band2 Inactive'], ['Emp3 Admin Band2 Active']]
```

Comment: My answer is probably not what OP is asking for, but the question is not well defined so I can't help. The expected output [['Emp1,Developer,Band1,Active'],['Emp2 Senior-Developer Band2 Inactive'],[Emp3 Admin Band2 Active]] has different pattern for line 1 and line 2, and line 3 is not even a valid Python expression.